# Shared Memory Access Terminates Process in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-3.11

```
_ORDER_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME: str = "OrderSharedMemory"
_TRADE_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME: str = "TradeSharedMemory"

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def _get_dataframe_from_shared_memory(
    shared_memory_name: str,
    shape: tuple[int, ...],
    dtype: np.dtype
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Get DataFrame from shared memory

    Note: cache used for this function has no maximum size and shared_memory with the same name might caused inconsistency

    Params:
        shared_memory_name(str): name of shared memory
        shape(tuple[int, ...]): shape of shared memory
        dtype(numpy.dtype): data type of shared memory
    """
    
    # Get shared memory instance
    shared_mem = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shared_memory_name)

    # Create a structured NumPy array from the shared memory
    np_array = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shared_mem.buf)

    # Convert the NumPy array to a DataFrame
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np_array)

    return dataframe

def _orderbook_job(
        cls: type["OrderBookHandler"],
        date: Date,
        security_code: str,
        orderbook_root_folder_path: str,
        orderbook_compression: str | None,
        order_shape: tuple[int, ...],
        trade_shape: tuple[int, ...],
        order_dtype: np.dtype,
        trade_dtype: np.dtype,
        include_snapshot_log: bool = False
    ):
        """
        Calculate and write orderbook based on shared memory data. This method is used as job in multiprocessing

        Params:
            date(utils.types.Date): specified date of tick data
            security_code(str): security code of stock
            orderbook_root_folder_path(str): root folder path for orderbook
            orderbook_compression(str): compression type for orderbook
            order_shared_memory_name(str): name of shared memory for order data
            trade_shared_memory_name(str): name of shared memory for trade data
            order_shape(tuple[int, ...]): shape of order data
            trade_shape(tuple[int, ...]): shape of trade data
            order_dtype(numpy.dtype): data type of order data
            trade_dtype(numpy.dtype): data type of trade data
            include_snapshot_log(bool): whether to include snapshot log
        """

        order_dataframe = _get_dataframe_from_shared_memory(
            _ORDER_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME,
            order_shape,
            order_dtype
        )

        trade_dataframe = _get_dataframe_from_shared_memory(
            _TRADE_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME,
            trade_shape,
            trade_dtype
        )

        orderbook_writer = cls.get_orderbook_writer(orderbook_root_folder_path, orderbook_compression)

        orderbook_writer.write_orderbook(
            date,
            security_code,
            order_dataframe,
            trade_dataframe,
            include_snapshot_log
        )
```

I have `_orderbook_job` as function that will be the job in multiprocessing. The function works fine until I tried to access `np_array` in `_get_dataframe_from_shared_memory`. When manually creating Process object that run `_orderbook_job`, it suddently halt at `dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np_array)`. When using process pool as above, it weirdly create 1 extra process and do nothing (tried interupting with Control-C but it needs infinite interupt, never be able to interupt all process. This might be not relevant to my problem). I don't use any lock as it is intended for read only.

Here is the main process code.

```
if (self.__multiprocessing):
            # Convert the DataFrame to a structured NumPy array
            order_np_array = order_dataframe.to_records(index=False)
            trade_np_array = trade_dataframe.to_records(index=False)

            # Create a shared memory block
            order_shared_memory = shared_memory.SharedMemory(
                name=_ORDER_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME,
                create=True, 
                size=order_np_array.nbytes
            )
            trade_shared_memory = shared_memory.SharedMemory(
                name=_TRADE_SHARED_MEMORY_NAME,
                create=True, 
                size=trade_np_array.nbytes
            )

            # Copy the NumPy array into the shared memory
            order_np_shared_array = np.ndarray(order_np_array.shape, dtype=order_np_array.dtype, buffer=order_shared_memory.buf)
            order_np_shared_array[:] = order_np_array[:]

            trade_np_shared_array = np.ndarray(trade_np_array.shape, dtype=trade_np_array.dtype, buffer=trade_shared_memory.buf)
            trade_np_shared_array[:] = trade_np_array[:]

            function_args: list[list[Any]] = [
                [
                    type(self),
                    date, 
                    code,
                    self.__orderbook_file_parser.get_root_folder(),
                    self.__orderbook_file_parser.get_compression(),
                    order_np_array.shape,
                    trade_np_array.shape,
                    order_np_array.dtype,
                    trade_np_array.dtype,
                    include_snaphot_log
                ] for code in security_codes
            ]

            self.__worker_pool.starmap(_orderbook_job, function_args)

            # Close the shared memory block
            order_shared_memory.close()
            trade_shared_memory.close()
```

I can assure you that it is not the problem of using @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None). Problem still occurs even when I remove it. Also tried to remove shared memory access in the subprocess and it run perfectly. The code also run in the single threaded mode with sucessful shared memory access.

Comment: Note that I am using windows OS, if it helps